# Image segmentation with pytorch

Tags: pytorch, model, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I have been trying to implement a image segmentation model by using work publised by Esertel et al., 2022, code available here: (https://github.com/burakekim/LULCMapping-WV3images-CORINE-DLMethods/blob/main/lulc_wv3.ipynb).

But I found difficulties to use it with main data (although, due to small PC RAM 16gb I used smaller images (32X32 pix)). During a sanity check I found that all masks are black and after trainig the masks are still blask and predictions are biased (see image), and that probably cause next problem which are related to very high metrics, i.g. validation:100 %, precicion-1.0, recall 1.0, etc.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4dWI.png)

As Iam very very beginner in AI, therefore probably also the problem is not described enough, anyway maybe somebody can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution which was very simple, I did not specified main RGB colors in palette.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).